# Playing multiple audio files at once in Ionic/ngCordova

Tags: javascript, angularjs, media, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I'm building an app in Ionic that needs to be able to play 2 audio files at the same time.

At first I tried to use the HTML5 Audio capabilities which allowed me to do that. However: on the web it played two sounds concurrently as desired but when running on my Android phone only 1 audio file gets played.

I looked further and found ngCordova's $cordovaMedia.
So I went ahead and used the info on ngCordova's website: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/media/
(and I included the js files)

Resulting in the following code:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ngCordova'])

.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaMedia, $ionicLoading) {

    $scope.play = function() {
        var media = $cordovaMedia.newMedia('http://www.tonycuffe.com/mp3/tail%20toddle.mp3');
        media.play();

        var media2 = $cordovaMedia.newMedia('http://www.tonycuffe.com/mp3/saewill.mp3');
        media2.play();

        console.log(media);
        console.log(media2);
    }
});
```

Both objects play fine seperate, but when played together only media2 is heard.

Anyone knows why this is and if I can fix it? I'm surely open to alternatives as well.

Comment: You have to read about mixing your sounds. https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html#AudioNode-section